# Replace element after amount of page refreshes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, replace

Today, I was thinking if a javascript is possible to replace an element after refreshing the page 10 times specifically. I would really need this to replace an element after amount of page refreshes to make it static. I was trying to code it but all, I coded so far is to replace it after clicking on the element 3 times. And localStorage logs it and creates a key so the webserver remembers the change. All, I want is the element to replace its code with urls code after 10 refreshes on the page.

```
var count = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("count"), 10) || 0;
function loadMyPage() {
    if (count >= 3)
        $("#id-2").load("yoinkexecutor2.html");
    }
}

$(document).ready( function () {
    loadMyPage();
    $("#id-2").on("click", function() {
        localStorage.setItem("count", count += 1);
        loadMyPage();
    });
});
```

Comment: I prefer to you for using Cookie instead localStorage. thats very easy and usable. you can see example on this url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript

Comment: Besides having a small syntax error around you if statement in `loadMyPage`, the code you provided seems to work find in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettgaynor/j84qwm2k/2/).

Comment: understandable @MohammadrezaYektamaram I might of used localStorage since it seems simpler. Also, I have tried the code, I posted in fiddle and it doesn't seem to work so, I just upload it to my webserver and it works fine. But yeah, I just need to make it replace the element after refreshing the page.

Comment: Of course, you can not store any data in fiddle website.

Comment: yea, hah fiddle is more like client sided javascript experimentation.

Comment: You actually can store localStorage items. It just logs to the devtools console, under for instance Application, if you are using Chrome. The only thing I found is that you have to clear that localStorage item, and hit the "Run" button at the top of the fiddle to start the count over.

Comment: @NateVang agree, but that was what it looked like you were doing from your code. But to your point, `.load()` won't really work.

Comment: @bgaynor78 ah then how would, I go about atleast changing the element after refreshing the page. Maybe to display: none;

Comment: Yeah, if you want to not show it, sure. But the `.load()` method you're using should replace the content of the `id-2` div with whatever comes back when `yoinkexecutor2.html` is loaded.

Comment: I agree it replaces the element when id="id-2" is assigned to it with yoinkexecutor2.html code. Whatever returns from yoinkexecutor2.html. Now maybe hiding the element with display: none; but would be simpler.

Comment: Something like $("#id-2").style('display', 'none'); @bgaynor78

Comment: If you're using Jquery, it's the method is `.css()` to `.css('display', 'none');`

Comment: alright, great. and are there any documentations on refreshment of page and maybe how to change the element after refreshing the page. i haven't found any so far. but if you have some knowledge, i'd appreciate. @bgaynor78

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettgaynor/j84qwm2k/12/) to work when the fiddle is reloaded. Don't worry too much about my `mockHtmlReq` function as it's just to mock a request for HTML content, similar to `.load()`.

The only thing I changed was inside the `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    loadMyPage();
    localStorage.setItem("count", count += 1);
});
```

Basically what happens is everytime the page reloads we are just incrementing up our `count` value stored in `localStorage`.